# count() rows in database using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is the model (Excel.php) :

```html
function undangan($req_id)
    {
        
        $this->db->select("excel_id,request_id,to_name as nama,to_address as alamat_tujuan,to_zipcode as kode_pos, ifnull(tariff,0) as tarif ");
        $this->db->where('tariff = 0 and request_id =', $req_id);
        $query  =   $this->db->get('excel');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

This is the controller (Admin.php) :

```html
function undangan()
    { 
     $this->load->model('excel');
        $this->load->model('request'); 
     $data['results']   =   $this->request->request();       
        foreach ( $data['results'] as $key)
        {
            $tarif=0;
            $req_id = $key['req'];
            $data['tarif'][$req_id] =   $this->excel->total_tarif($req_id); 
            $data['undg'][$req_id]   =   $this->excel->undangan($req_id);
            foreach ($data['undg'][$req_id] as $value)
            {

                $tarif += $value['tarif']; 
                $this->db->where('request_id', $value['request_id']);
                $num_rows = $this->db->count_all_results('excel');
                var_dump($num_rows);
            }
           
            $tarif = $data['tarif'][$req_id];
        }
           
        $this->load->view('admin_view',$data);
          
    }
```

And the view (admin_view.php) :

```html
<div class="container">
<h3>Customer Request</h3>

<?php
    foreach ($results as $value) {
  
    ?>
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <table class="table" align="center">
       
            <tr class="primary" align="center">

                <td><?php echo $value['nama']?></td>

                <td><?php echo $value['email']?></td>

                <td><?php echo $value['phone']; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo $value['alamat_pengirim']?></td>  
                
                <td id="total_<?php echo $value['req']?>">
                <span > <?php echo $tarif[$value['req']][0]['tarif']?>
                </td>

                <td>
                <button id="kirim_email" type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick=update_status(<?php echo $value['req']?>) >
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true" ></span> Kirim Email
                </button>
                </td>

                <td>
                <button  type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick=tariff(<?php echo $value['req']?>)>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true" ></span> Auto Tarif
                </button>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>  


    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" align="center" width="400px" >
        <tr align="center" class="success">
            <th>
                Alamat
            </th>
            <th>
                Zip Code
            </th>
            
            <th>
                Tarif
            </th>
            
            <th>
                Action
            </th>
        </tr>
  
        <?php        
         foreach ($undg[$value['req']] as $row) {        
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <?php echo $row['alamat_tujuan']?>
            </td>

            <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-2"  id="zip_<?php echo $row['excel_id']?>"  value="<?php echo $row['kode_pos']?>">
            </td>

            <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-2"  id="<?php echo $row['excel_id']?>"  name="tariff" value="<?php echo $row['tarif']?>">
            </td>

            <td>
            <button  type="button" id="ref_butn" class="btn btn-md" onclick="update(<?php echo $row['excel_id']?> )">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save" aria-hidden="true" ></span> Save
            </button>
            </td>

        </tr>
    <?php    } ?>
    </table>
    <?php }; ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to count rows from table excel where 'request_id' = something..
I did the count_all_result inside foreach in controller, but it gives me :

```html
int(3) int(3) int(3) int(3) int(3) int(3) int(2) int(2) int(3) int(3) int(3) int(2) int(2)
```

This is not the actual total of rows. Where i should count_all_result? Help me to solve this.. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `count` in your select query.

```
$this->db->select("COUNT(request_id) as total, excel_id,request_id,to_name as nama,to_address as alamat_tujuan,to_zipcode as kode_pos, ifnull(tariff,0) as tarif ");
$this->db->where('tariff = 0 and request_id =', $req_id);
```

or use

```
$total = $this->db->count();
```

Comment: but it gives me the total where tariff = 0. I want to count all the rows where `request_id`= something.. Thanks for your help @urfusion

Comment: in that case you need to write a new query. `$this->db->where('request_id =', $req_id);`

Comment: you mean, a new function in my model or two query in one function?

Comment: you can do that by both of the ways. choose your own :)

Comment: i created a new function for return result_array from count, but in the view, it gives me undefined index 'total'

Comment: i create a new function in my model, called function total_rows that consist the COUNT query you suggest me, but it give me undefined index 'total'.. I think i should add something in my controller, but i dont know how

Comment: try `$data['undg'][$total]   =   $this->excel->functionName($req_id);` in your controller and print the value of `$data['undg'][$total] `

Comment: undefined variable $total in controller :(

Comment: sorry it should be `$data['undg'][$req_id]['total']`

Comment: could you please tell me where I should put your suggestion? because it always gives me an undefined variable, i'm not sure where to put the code

Comment: put it after ` $data['undg'][$req_id]   =   $this->excel->undangan($req_id);` and print it

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$u->where('test', $test);
$u->where('test', $test);
$u->get();
$total = count($u->all);
```